# Increasing ever towards 100 percentage function

Tags: math, percentage

So. I have a function, and it works as i want it to, but it can get a bit heavy in the long run, this i was wondering if there was a better way to do this:

```
float getPval(float i) {
    float retunrVal = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
      returnVal += (100 - returnVal)/2;
    }
  returnVal += ((100-returnVal)/2)*(i - (int)i);
  Return returnVal;
}
```

Basicly, if i write:

```
getPval(1) I'll get 50 back.
getPval(1.5) would return 62,5
getPval(2) would return 75.
getPval(3) 87.5
getPval(4) 93.75
getPval(4.2) 94.375
```

and so on... 
No matter how high a number, it will never return 100, but it will get ever closer.

Is there a better function instead of my getPval(flaot)?

Now, stupidly formulated I know, but I have no idea what to call such a formula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at each step in the loop, it finds half the difference between the `returnVal` and 100. Then adds this to the return value.

Another way of think about this is to find 100 (1 - 0.5^i ). In java you would implement this as

```
returnVal = 100. * ( 1.0 - Math.pow(0.5,Math.floor(i)) );
returnVal += ((100-returnVal)/2)*(i - (int)i);
```

You might even find its better just to use

```
returnVal = 100. * ( 1.0 - Math.pow(0.5,i) );
```

which will give different result for non-integer arguments.

Comment: Awesome, that does exactly what i wanted :)